# Build.gradle Formatting: How to stop colon alignment?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, code-formatting

I'm currently fighting with the groovy auto-formatter in my build.gradle. Does anyone know what settings I should tweak to get to my desired format? I want to prevent the colons from being aligned.

```
// Current Format
ext.versions = ['supportLibrary': '27.1.0',
                'kotlin'        : '1.2.31',
                'dagger'        : '2.15',]

// Desired Format
ext.versions = ['supportLibrary': '27.1.0',
                'kotlin': '1.2.31',
                'dagger': '2.15',]
```

Comment: Just curious, why did you want it to not aligned? The first format is more readable and straightforward. Imagine fi you have 20 line of it without the first format. You will lost in the words.

Comment: I'm trying to format my build.gradle like this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/SdkSearch/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Code Style > Groovy > Wrapping uncheck this:

[image: List and map literals > Align multiline named arguments]